# How to know which form called another form in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I am having multiple forms with Find button provided. The forms i am having are Contacts.vb and Users.vb, i want to use single Find.vb form for both of these forms. I mean whether a user presses Find button from Contacts.vb or Users.vb the same form should be opened with corresponding data that is fetched from database.

I tried using `Find.Owner = Me` from Users.vb but i don't know how can i determine from Find.vb that who is the owner.

I tried to use that if owner of find form is Users.vb then fetch data from users table and if owner is Contacts.vb then fetch data from Contacts table. 
Unfortunately i am not able to perform this task.

Please provide any proper solution or any other suggestion to perform this. 
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 9):

Call your children form using:

```
frmChildren.ShowDialog(Me)
```

Now, how to know which form called to the parent form?
Using:

```
Me.Owner.Name
```

for example...

```
if Me.Owner.Name = "frmMain" then
   MessageBox.Show("YES! Its called from frmMain")
else
   MessageBox.Show("Its called from " & Me.Owner.Name)
End If
```

Maybe you need exactly this:

```
'To call your form Find.vb from a command button. (for example)
Find.ShowDialog(Me)

'How to know which form call to Find.vb ?
If Me.Owner.Name = "Contacts" then
   'Actions for Contacts
ElseIf Me.Owner.Name = "Users" then
   'Actions for Users
else
   'Actions for NOT"Contacts" and NOT"Users"
end if
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add a property to Find form as follows:

```
Private findTypeValue As FindType
Public Property FindType As FindType
Get
Return findTypeValue
End Get
Set (value as FindType)
findTypeValue = value
End Set
```

And create Enum for the property:

```
Public Enum FindType As Integer
Contacts = 0
Users= 1
End Enum
```

Then in Find form check the type:

```
If FindType = FindType.Contacts Then
...
Else

End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a property (e.g. "PersonType") to the child form - set this from the parent just before showing the form - and then use the value of this property in the child to perform the correct search type.