# How to find parent form name ? vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

I want the name of the parent form in vb.net . Where I came from.

Like

```
`if parent-form.name = 'something' then
    do something.
else
   do something else.`
```

It's not a MDI form.

**Edit:**
I want exactly like that:

**parentForm.vb:**

```
chidform.showdialog()
```

In childform there is `textbox`

**childForm.vb:**

```
if parentForm is parentForm1 than fill textbox.text = 2 
else fill textbox.text = 3
```

You will understand what I want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to know which form called another form in vb.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377068/how-to-know-which-form-called-another-form-in-vb-net)

Comment: But this code does not work for me.
`Me.Owner.Name` does not work for me. It shows the error.

Comment: Do you mean parent form as in MDI container? I'm assuming this is `Windows.Forms` related.

Comment: Why are you comparing names rather than object identity? It’s *almost certainly* not what you should do.

Comment: It's not a MDI form
I want exactly like that:
**parentForm.vb:**


`chidform.showdialog()`

In childform there is `textbox`

**childForm.vb:**


`if parentForm is parentForm1 than fill textbox.text = 2 else fill textbox.text = 3`

You will understand.
So help me.

Answer (score 2):

**Assumption:** I worked under the assumption that this is an MDI application and you would want to read the name of the top parent and for reasons unknown you cannot refer to a singleton reference to the form (for instance current form runs from a library).

I wrote an extension mode to get the top parent since the immediate parent of an MDI child window is an `MDIClient` without a name.

```
<Extension>
Public Function GetTopParent(currentControl As Control) As Control
    Dim parent As Control = Nothing

    Do While currentControl IsNot Nothing
        parent = If(currentControl.Parent, parent)
        currentControl = currentControl.Parent
    Loop

    Return parent
End Function
```

Then when you need the name of the parent you can do the following.

```
MessageBox.Show(Me.GetTopParent().Name) ' This just shows the name but you can do your comparison here.
```

Comment: It's not a MDI form
I want exactly like that:
**parentForm.vb:**


`chidform.showdialog()`

In childform there is `textbox`

**childForm.vb:**


`if parentForm is parentForm1 than fill textbox.text = 2 else fill textbox.text = 3`

You will understand.
So help me.

Comment: You cannot set the Parent property for a form at runtime so you cannot call the parent. What you can do is specify the current form when showing childForm as follows: `childform1.ShowDialog(Me)` and in the child form, you can test for `.Owner` and proceed as required.